# How to add custom css in magento footer pages

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, css

How do I add custom CSS or JS to for a particular page?

Suppose,i want add a custom css file for Checkout cart which  will only show n at Cart.

Example: like a FAQ or any single page

Answer (score 3):

if you want to add a css file to all cms pages add this to your local.xml

```
<layout>
    <cms_page_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
               <type>skin_css</type>
               <name>path/to/file.css</name>
            </action>
       </reference>
    </cms_page_view>
</layout>
```

If you want a css file just for the FAQ page, go to that CMS page and go to Design tab in the left menu and insert:

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type><name>path/to/file.css</name>
  </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add some CSS/JS files **only** in local.xml file in your magento theme.

app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/TEMPLATE/layout/local.xml

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>path/to/file.js</script>
            </action>

            <action method="addItem">
               <type>skin_css</type>
               <name>path/to/file.css</name>
            </action>
       </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2013/10/24/adding-javascript-and-css-files-to-head-section-of-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find the related `phtml` pages, here in your file directory

```
/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/page
```

depending on your theme, you might see files named

```
1column.phtml
2columns-left.phtml
2columns-right.phtml
3columns.phtml
```

You can find the **header section** in those files, where you can link your CSS files or `js`

Comment: Editing the .phtml files is not the correct way of adding a stylesheet.